# Overlay Constraint layout with imported layout

Tags: android, user-interface, kotlin

I'm currently using a virtual base class, that derives from Activity. Every view I create extends this virtual base class. The base class does the handling of the top bar, timer, and application wide used buttons like an audio slider and an exit button. Everything works fine and as expected, except a custom overlay message, which consists of a view with opacity and a black background and a layout with two buttons in it.

On some views the alert message is drawn over the view as expected, but on some others some view-specific buttons are drawn on top.

The import of the xml is alwas at the bottom, due i know the elements that come last will be drawn on top.

Is there a way to set these elements to go in front and overlay all other ui elemets?

Things like

```
bringToFront();
```

or

```
elevation="3dp"
```

doesn't work.

Base class:

```
abstract class BasicFeatures : Activity(), SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener, Observer {...}
```

one of the derived classes

```
class SomeActualView: BasicFeatures() {...}




    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     tools:context=".kotlin.ui.activity.SomeActualView">

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/ui_content"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginEnd="250dp"
     android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
     android:gravity="center_horizontal"
     android:textSize="@dimen/default_font_size"
     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

.
.
.

```
 <Button
     android:id="@+id/ui_name_number_bt_skip"
     style="@style/customButton"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
     android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
     app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

 <include
     android:id="@+id/main_bot_layout"
     layout="@layout/ui_basic_layout"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

The button above the include is on some views drawn over the include and sometimes not.
Is there a way to set the included elements allways in top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due the overlay hasn't really wokred for me, because the overlay sometimes worked, and sometimes not, I created a custom message dialog, which inherits from the Dialog class. Then I simply styled it the way I wanted it to look like and overrided the onCreate method.
In the constructor I handed over everything i needed. The most effort was needed to subscribe/unsubscribe both, the dialog and the view correctly to keep working correctly

Here how I created my custom dialog:

```
class CustomMessageDialog(val a: Activity, val message: String, val acceptText: String, val declineText: String, val acceptCall: () -> Unit, val declineCall: () -> Unit,val observable:Observable) : Dialog(a), Observer {

override fun update(observable: Observable?, property: Any?) {
    if (property is TimeoutReason && a is BasicFeatures)
        when (property) {
            TimeoutReason.NO_USER_INPUT -> a.setTimeoutManager(10, TimeoutReason.NO_USER_PRESENT)
            TimeoutReason.NO_USER_PRESENT -> {
                dismiss()
                a.restart()
            }
        }
}


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_message_dialog_custom)
    window.setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
    window.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT))
    val accept = findViewById<Button>(R.id.ui_alert_bt_accept)
    val decline = findViewById<Button>(R.id.ui_alert_bt_decline)
    val content = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.ui_alert_tv_text)
    content.text = message
    accept.text = acceptText
    decline.text = declineText
    accept.setOnClickListener { handle(acceptCall) }
    decline.setOnClickListener { handle(declineCall) }
}

private fun handle(call: () -> Unit) {
    observable.deleteObserver(this)
    dismiss()
    call()
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your BaseActivity doesn't need to be abstract. If it's not, you can inflate a basic XML in it, with a container (1) and your include. Then each activity that extends your BaseActivity would define its layout (without the include), and in onCreate() call super, and then a custom method (of your choice) that would load the layout of the current Activity *inside* of the container of the BaseActivity's XML. Consider something like this:

Your activity_base.xml:

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/activityContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <include yourIncludeWithTheButtons/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Your activity_main.xml:

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/background"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Your BaseActivity:

```
open class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
protected lateinit var activityContainer: RelativeLayout

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_base)
    activityContainer = findViewById(R.id.activityContainer)
}
}
```

And lastly, your MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity: BaseActivity(): {
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) //Base will inflate the root
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) //Don't call this
    layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, activityContainer)
}
}
```

This way, your BaseActivity always inflates the activity_base, which sets a container for the content, and buttons on top.
Then, every activity that extends BaseActivity will (via super.onCreate()) have this activity_base inflated, and will be able to populate the container with the view it wants to display.

Comment: Now i have adopted my app that way, but the result is still nearly the same except it's now not even overlaying the list at the head

Comment: I'm not sure what you're facing now. Could you update your question with the output? What list?